# ng-repeat and textarea focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

**UPDATE**: "textareashow" is:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" data-ngshow="textareashow">
   <div id="replyBox">
      <textarea cols="65" rows="7" maxlength="300" data-ng-model="texta" autofocus="autofocus" data-ng-focus="focus()" data-ng-blur="blur()"></textarea>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Submit answer</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have `ng-repeat` and inside the loop I have:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="ans_button" data-ng-click="textareashow = !textareashow">Answer</button>
<textarea cols="65" rows="7" data-ng-model="texta" autofocus="autofocus" data-ng-focus="focus()" data-ng-blur="blur()"></textarea>
```

I want that if the user click on "answer" `button` the `textarea` will be shown.
It's working, but only once, if I click on it and close, and after that click on another answer `button` - the `textarea` won't be focused.

Comment: show us the code of focus method, please

Comment: there is no method - just autofocus="autofocus"

Comment: this method: `data-ng-focus="focus()"`

Comment: @user11001, how do you show/hide textarea ? I suppose that  textareashow variable is a switch. But i don`t understand how it connected with textarea

Comment: <div class = "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" data-ng-show="textareashow"> 
with the textarea inside

Comment: try to change data-ng-show to data-ng-if

Comment: @user11001 have you tried ng-if instead ng-show ?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: "textareashow" at self place

Change your html like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="ans_button" data-ng-click="textareashow = !textareashow;doAnswer($event)">Answer</button>
<textarea  cols="65" rows="7" data-ng-model="texta" autofocus="autofocus" data-ng-focus="focus()" data-ng-blur="blur()"></textarea>
```

And in your controller js:

```
$scope.doAnswer = function(event){
    angular.element(event.target).next().focus();
}
```

Comment: Please give more detail, what's "textareashow" in your html?